# Why are the outputs of the parent process and child process intertwined in xv6?

Tags: c, operating-system, xv6

I am learning about xv6 and I create a program like below from a xv6 document:

```
#include"types.h"
#include"user.h"
#include"param.h"

int main(){
    int pid;
    pid=fork();
    if(pid > 0){
            printf(0,"parent: child=%d\n", pid);
            pid = wait();
            printf(0,"child %d is done\n", pid);
    }
    else if(pid == 0){
            printf(0,"child: exiting\n");
            exit();
    }
    else {
            printf(0,"fork error\n");
    }
}
```

I use the `wait()` syscall to make sure the output of the two processes separated
but they're not:

```
$ test
cphiarlde:n tex:iti ncg
hild=4
child 4 is done
pid 3 test: trap 14 err 5 on cpu 0 eip 0xffffffff addr 0xffffffff--kill proc
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Apparently this stdio library doesn't buffer output. So both the parent and child are writing their messages one character at a time, and they get interleaved.

Comment: You need to use some kind of mutex to coordinate writing to the terminal.

Comment: You're not calling `wait` correctly.  If it's the standard Unix [`wait`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait), it takes an argument.

Comment: But I check the source code of  `wait`  in xv6,actually it doesn't need argument.

Comment: I think printf in xv6 is not thread safe. Use sleep statement in between. you can by pass the issue